# React-spring Transition didn't repeat animation

Tags: reactjs, react-spring

In my react app I have component, where I using `Transition` from `react-spring`.

```
import { Transition } from 'react-spring'

export class myComponent {
 state = {
   items: []
 }

 static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state){
    const newItems = [...props.items]

    if(props.items !== state.items){
      return {items: newItems}
    }
 }

 render() {
  const { items } = this.state

        <Transition
        items={items}
        keys={item => items.id}
        initial={{ opacity: 1, height: 'auto' }}
        from={{ opacity: 0, height: 0 }}
        enter={{ opacity: 1, height: 'auto' }}
        leave={{ opacity: 0, height: 0 }}
      >
        {item => propsAnimations => (
          <section style={propsAnimations}>
            <Item
              key={item.selectionId}
            />
          </section>
        )}
      </Transition>
 }
}
```

But when I updating `this.state.items` this is didn't repeat animation. 
When I updating `items` in state, I change only elements order in array.

Comment: is there a reason you can't just use the items from the props in render?

Comment: @WillJenkins this is didn't change situation with animations. Still it's run animation only 1 time, and didn't repeat it when I update `items`.

Comment: Ok, best to avoid the getDerivedState stuff if possible. So if your prop items are definitely updating, maybe it's that your keys (items.id and item.selectionId) are not changing, so it isn't triggering a transition. Have you tried removing your key mapping so it uses the default? (item => item)